# eglibc-2.11.3: where is libc-2.11.3.so? Not there after compilation

Tags: c, debian, glibc, libc

I compiled eglibc-2.11.3 on Debian squeeze, but do not see the libc-2.11.3.so. I believe that this is symlinked to from libc.so.6.

Not a c expert, so bear with me. These are the steps I took according to the included install file plus debian patch:

```
apt-get source libc6    # gets me eglibc-2.11.3
```

In build directory:

```
../configure --prefix=/usr
make -f ../debian/rules patch
make
```

I didn't see any errors before it gave me back the prompt, am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure the patching worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> do not see the libc-2.11.3.so

The library is linked as `libc.so.6` (should be in the directory in which you executed `make`).

`make install` is what should create `libc-2.11.3.so` and a symlink `libc.so.6` in the installation directory.

You may want to try `make install PREFIX=/tmp/glibc-install` and examine the resulting install tree, to make sure everything is where you expect it.

Comment: I had understood this in reverse -- libc-2.11.3.so -> libc.so.6. Thanks for clarifying that.

Answer (score 0):

In `debian/quiltrc` change

```
QUILT_PATCH_OPTS="--unified-reject-files"
```

to become

```
QUILT_PATCH_OPTS="--reject-format=unified"
```